# pre-trained Keras/ Tensorflow models in Matlab

Tags: matlab, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

It seems that the Matlab Keras importer allows us to use the models trained by Keras/ Tensorflow and we can use that in Matlab. In all their documentation, they have used image input and for a CNN model.  I have created a simple feedforward ANN model in keras and the inputs are not images. Does the Matlab Keras importer only work for image inputs or for CNN Models? Though Matlab is able to read the model and the give the activation function, a number of hidden layers and other things accurately, when I check the classifier output in Keras and Matlab, They answers are not matching. Can someone please clarify this?
Here is the Matlab code

```
clear  
close all  
classnames={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6'}; % Number of classes I have  
model16 = importKerasNetwork('model16.json','WeightFile','model16.h5','classnames',classnames,'OutputLayerType','classification');   
model16.Layers % Displays the architecture of the network
load 'feature_vector_newtra360_48Khz.mat' % Load the feature vector used to test the classifier 
A=featurevec(1,1:37); %  taking one feature vector to classify  
ans = classify(model16,A); % command used to classify
```

Here I have taken the model from keras.I can see the architecture perfectly when I use model16.layers command . But, when I gave an input to classify, the answers in Matlab and keras are not matching. Have I made any mistakes?

Comment: Can you show us your matlab code as well?

Comment: Hi, I have changed the question. Please have a look at it